# New Node undefined in jsTree even thou its visually there

Tags: jstree

Hello I have issues selected newly created nodes in jsTree. Every time the user wants to add a node i let them rename it and hit enter. Initially I create the node with a temporaryID and after they hit enter I am writing code in the .bind("rename_node.jstree", function(...){}) where I'm grabbing the new text they entered + their parent name and making that the new id of the node.

I found a jsfiddle that was doing the regular node adding and modified to reflect closer what i'm doing in my actual code.

http://jsfiddle.net/p0bchhmt/

I'm guessing changing the id on the fly does not work this way. Any thought on how to accomplish this with jstree? 
Thanks

```js
function tree() {
    var self = this;

    //display actions in fiddle
    self.consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";
    self.consoleLog = function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(self.consoleLine).html(text));
    };
    self.clearConsoleLog = function () {
        $("#console-log").html('');
    };


    self.tree = $('#jstree_demo_div'); //get jstree div
    self.isNodeSelected = ko.observable(false);
    self.selectedNode = ko.observable({});

    //deselect all nodes
    self.deselectAllNodes = function () {
        self.tree.jstree('deselect_all');
    }

    //keep track of selected node
    self.tree.on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
        var node = self.tree.jstree().get_selected(true)[0]; //get current selected node
            self.isNodeSelected(true);
            self.selectedNode(node);
            self.consoleLog('selected node id: ' + node.id);
    });
 
   self.tree.bind("rename_node.jstree", function(event, data){
      data.node.id = data.node.parent + "," + data.node.text;
        self.tree.treedata.push(data.node);
    });
    
    self.createFileNode = function (data) {
        var data = {
            'id': 'tempId',
                'text': 'iOS 8'
        }
        //create file node
        var id = self.tree.jstree("create_node", self.selectedNode(), data, 'last');
        self.tree.jstree('open_node', self.selectedNode());
        self.tree.jstree('edit', id);
    };

    self.treeData = ko.observableArray([{
        'id': 1,
            'parent': '#',
            'text': 'Animals'
    }, {
        'id': 2,
            'parent': '#',
            'text': 'Devices'
    }, {
        'id': 'dog',
            'parent': 1,
            'text': 'Dogs'
    }]);
};

ko.bindingHandlers.jstree = {
    buildTree: function (element, treeData) {
        $(element).jstree('destroy');
        $(element).jstree({
            'core': {
                'animation': 0,
                    'check_callback': true,
                    'data': treeData
            },
                'plugins': [
                'state'
                ]
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var treeData = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        ko.bindingHandlers.jstree.buildTree(element, treeData.data());
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new tree());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bind="click: createFileNode">Create Node</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-bind="click: clearConsoleLog">Clear Log</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-bind="click: deselectAllNodes">Deselect All</button>

        <div id="jstree_demo_div" data-bind="jstree: { data: treeData }"></div>
    <div>--js tree log below--</div>
    <div id="console-log"></div>
    <!-- <div id="jstree_demo_dev_attributes">
        <ul>
          <li>Attribute Reporting Group
            <ul>
              <li>Invoice Dates</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div> --></div>
```

Comment: To clarify the question a bit more: What's the best way to update the jstree new node id dynamically after the user has renamed it cause apparently the way i'm doing it is not working out.   -Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change id of a node use `set_id` method.
So in your case it could look like below.

Check demo - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/p0bchhmt/1/).

```
self.tree.bind("rename_node.jstree", function(event, data){
    var newId = data.node.parent + "," + data.node.text;;
    self.tree.jstree().set_id(data.node, newId);     
});
```

Comment: Hi Nikolay! 
Thanks so much for your prompt and helpful answers as usual. I did notice a similar bug that still occurs in the fiddle you've posted. If you don't mind to test the following steps in your fiddle and see if you can reproduce the bug I'm referring to: 

`Add Node1 under Dog > click Node1 > add Node2 under Node1`  

At this point, I am unable to select Node2 and jstree thinks I've selected Node1. Let me know if you get a chance to reproduce this and if you have any help on how to fix this. 

Thanks again

Comment: I suggest removing the `'id': 'tempId',` part in `self.createFileNode` function. This works - http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/p0bchhmt/2/

Comment: Ok that makes sense! This works! thanks so much for your help! :)